# Height of one div affecting another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs both with the same class and when I add content to one the height of the other also changes.

```js
function addContent() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('list')[1].innerHTML += "<h1>test</h1>"
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 79%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bansContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list {
  background-color: #436935;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bansContainer">
    <div class="list">
      <h1>
        left
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1 class="list">
        right
      </h1>
      <button onclick=addContent()>Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I change/update it in a way that only the height of the div with content being added changes?

Comment: It is bcoz of bansContainer display, Unless specified, it will take height of max height of child. Try adding `  align-items: flex-start` to bansContainer in css

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addContent() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('list')[1].innerHTML += "<h1>test</h1>"
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 79%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bansContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list {
  background-color: #436935;
align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bansContainer">
    <div class="list">
      <h1>
        left
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1 class="list">
        right
      </h1>
      <button onclick=addContent()>Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you haven't specified height on the first column and it's continuing to adapt the height of its parent div aka `bansContainer`. So here are two approaches. One is you add `align-self: flex-start;` or you specify a height on the column.

```js
function addContent() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('list')[1].innerHTML += "<h1>test</h1>"
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 79%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bansContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list {
  background-color: #436935;
  /*align-self: flex-start;*/
}
.n-h {
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bansContainer">
    <div class="list n-h">
      <h1>
        left
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1 class="list">
        right
      </h1>
      <button onclick=addContent()>Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```